# Conversion of mixed ASCII string with multi-byte sequences to proper UTF-8

Tags: php, string, utf-8, ascii, multibyte

Please consider the following ASCII string that comes in from a CSV file:

```
Foo\xe2\x80\x99s Bar
```

Using PHP, how can one reliably convert this to UTF-8 so that the value is:

```
Foo’s Bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the string value printed as `Foo\xe2\x80\x99s Bar`, then in php the string can be defined like this

```
$str = "Foo\\xE2\\x80\\x99s Bar";
```

You can get the string printed as `Foo’s Bar` using the `eval()` method.

```
eval("\$value = \"Foo\\xE2\\x80\\x99s Bar\";");
echo $value;
```

The result display `Foo’s Bar`.